# Gooddata.UI - charts are not shown, table without formatting

Tags: gooddata

I am trying to finish the [intro tutorial](https://sdk.gooddata.com/gooddata-ui/docs/ht_create_your_first_visualization.html) for Gooddata.ui. However,  I am not able to see any chart. I can see loading bullets, but no charts.

To be more specific:

- a line chart is shown just for a short time and then it disappears (just a blick)
- a bar chart is not shown at all
- a table is shown without formatting

My code looks like this (I removed all the things from create-react-app) :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { LineChart, BarChart, Table } from '@gooddata/react-components';

...

class App extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
           <div style={{ height: 300 }}>
                <Table
                    projectId="xms7ga4tf3g3nzucd8380o2bev8oeknp"
                    measures={measures}
                />
            </div>
            <div style={{ height: 300 }}>
                <LineChart
                    projectId="xms7ga4tf3g3nzucd8380o2bev8oeknp"
                    measures={measures}
                    trendBy={attribute}
                    config={{
                        colors: [ '#14b2e2']
                    }}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default App;
```

Please, could you help me to find the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks you forgot to add the following line of the code to load the CSS:

```
import '@gooddata/react-components/styles/css/main.css';
```

See step 2 in [part 6 of the tutorial](https://sdk.gooddata.com/gooddata-ui/docs/ht_create_your_first_visualization.html#step-6-add-gooddata-components).